# Credit card validation form error at delete

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm not sure where the error is coming from, if the models, forms or views, most likely the form. I got the editing the form working, also adding a new credit card works, but when I try to delete a credit card object I get this error:

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/Arturo/anaconda3/envs/SoftEngVEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/Arturo/anaconda3/envs/SoftEngVEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/Arturo/anaconda3/envs/SoftEngVEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/Arturo/anaconda3/envs/SoftEngVEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Arturo/Documents/Arturo/Knowledge_center/Computer_Science/Projects/GitHub/Software Engineering 1/softwareEngineering_Group2/bookStore/users/views.py" in creditCardChange
  185.         if user_CreditCardForm.is_valid():

File "/Users/Arturo/anaconda3/envs/SoftEngVEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  185.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/Users/Arturo/anaconda3/envs/SoftEngVEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  180.             self.full_clean()

File "/Users/Arturo/anaconda3/envs/SoftEngVEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  382.         self._clean_form()

File "/Users/Arturo/anaconda3/envs/SoftEngVEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  409.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "/Users/Arturo/Documents/Arturo/Knowledge_center/Computer_Science/Projects/GitHub/Software Engineering 1/softwareEngineering_Group2/bookStore/users/forms.py" in clean
  121.         number = self.cleaned_data['number']

Exception Type: KeyError at /settings/billing/creditcard/6/
Exception Value: 'number'
```

And this is my **forms.py**

```
class CreditCardForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreditCardForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'My Discover'
        self.fields['number'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'id': 'creditcard-number'}))
        self.fields['number'].widget.attrs[
            'placeholder'] = '123456789'
        self.fields['expdate_month'] = ChoiceField(choices=MONTHS)
        self.fields['expdate_year'] = ChoiceField(choices=YEARS)
        self.fields['securitycode'].widget.attrs[
            'placeholder'] = '123'

    class Meta:
        model = CreditCard
        fields = [
            'name', 'number', 'expdate_month', 'expdate_year', 'securitycode'
        ]

    def clean(self):
        # errors
        self.error_messages = []

        # Card number block
        number = self.cleaned_data['number']

        visa_pattern = r'^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$'
        mastercard_pattern = r'^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}$'
        americanexpress_pattern = r'^3[47][0-9]{13}$'
        discover_pattern = r'^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$'

        patterns_list = [
            discover_pattern,
            visa_pattern,
            mastercard_pattern,
        ]
        pattern_string = '|'.join(patterns_list)

        pattern1 = re.compile(pattern_string)  # 3 digits of security code
        pattern2 = re.compile(
            americanexpress_pattern)  # four digits security code

        if pattern1.match(str(number)):
            security_code_pattern = re.compile(r'^[0-9]{3}$')  # 3
        elif pattern2.match(str(number)):
            security_code_pattern = re.compile(r'^[0-9]{4}$')  # 4
        else:
            security_code_pattern = None

        if not pattern1.match(str(number)) and not pattern2.match(str(number)):
            self.error_messages.append('Credit card number not valid')
            # self._errors['number'] = 'Please enter a valid credit card number'

        # Expiration date block
        month = int(self.cleaned_data['expdate_month'])
        year = int(self.cleaned_data['expdate_year'])
        expdate = datetime.datetime(year, month, 1)  # first day of the month
        today = datetime.datetime.today()

        if expdate < today:
            self.error_messages.append('Card has expired')

        # Security code block
        security_code = self.cleaned_data['securitycode']

        # if not security_code_pattern created or does not match the work the errors
        if not security_code_pattern or not security_code_pattern.match(
                str(security_code)):
            self.error_messages.append('Invalid security code')
            # self._errors[
            #     'securitycode'] = 'Please verify the credit card security code'

        self.error_message = ''
        if len(self.error_messages):
            self.error_message = ' & '.join(self.error_messages)
            raise forms.ValidationError(' & '.join(self.error_messages))

        return self.cleaned_data


class DeleteCreditCardConfirmation(forms.Form):
    pass
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def creditCardChange(request, creditcard_slug):

    # Gets name of the credit card based on id
    currentCreditCard = CreditCard.objects.all().get(pk=creditcard_slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_CreditCardForm = CreditCardForm(request.POST, instance=currentCreditCard)

        if user_CreditCardForm.is_valid():
            user_CreditCardForm.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your address has been updated successfully')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
        elif DeleteCreditCardConfirmation():
            currentCreditCard.delete()
            return redirect('settings:billing-settings')
        else:
            messages.warning(
                request, f'There were some errors updating you credit card.')

    else:
        user_CreditCardForm = CreditCardForm(instance=currentCreditCard)

    context = {
        'creditcard_slug': creditcard_slug,
        'user_CreditCardForm': user_CreditCardForm,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/creditCardChange.html', context)
```

**html**

```
   <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{user_CreditCardForm |crispy}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{DeleteCreditCardConfirmation |crispy}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

It's telling me that I have an error on the line that says: `number = self.cleaned_data['number']`. How can I fix this error? This only happens when I delete a credit card object.

Thank you

Comment: If you're deleting a credit card then maybe your code shouldn't get to this line in your view: `if user_CreditCardForm.is_valid():` which is causing the problem. Would you be able to share the relevant view and html to be able to help further?

Comment: @damores any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try knowing which form was submitted by adding the `name` attribute to the buttons:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" name="save_changes">Save changes</button>
...
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
```

Then in your view:

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
    if 'save_changes' in request.POST: # handle editing form
        user_CreditCardForm = CreditCardForm(request.POST, instance=currentCreditCard)

        if user_CreditCardForm.is_valid():
        ...
    elif 'delete' in request.POST: # handle deleting
        ...
```

That way when you delete you won't get to `if user_CreditCardForm.is_valid():` which is causing the problem.